# Spring Batch SQL Command with JobParameters

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring-batch, here i am getting some data from DB using following reader statements. Here i need to pass value dynamically(thru arguments).

```
<bean id="ItemReader"
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="sql">
                <value>
                <![CDATA[
    select * from table where section = #{jobParameters['section']}
    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
            <property name="rowMapper">
                <bean class="xyzRowMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
```

JUnit Code:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("section", section);
```

Can any body help on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549265/passing-jobparameters-to-bean-in-spring-batch?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [§5.4 Late Binding of Job and Steps Attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html) of official Spring Batch documentation, you need to add `scope="step"` to your step :

> Using a scope of Step is required in order to use late binding since
>   the bean cannot actually be instantiated until the Step starts, which
>   allows the attributes to be found. Because it is not part of the
>   Spring container by default, the scope must be added explicitly,
>   either by using the batch namespace or by including a bean definition
>   explicitly for the StepScope (but not both)

Giving this :

```
<bean id="ItemReader" scope="step" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                select * from table where section = #{jobParameters['section']}
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="xyzRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @Thrax Is there any way that I can pass property file value ?