# Get input query from batch parameters

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch

I need to retrive dynamically a parameter from the batch arguments and set it to my query. Here is my implementation :

```
<bean id="Reader" scope="step"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory"
        ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <property name="queryString"
        value="SELECT distinct d FROM ReglementClient r 
                   JOIN FETCH d.etablissement e 
                   WHERE e.code = #{jobParameters[code]}
                   And r.statut in('Validé')
                " />

</bean>
```

I run my batch usine the following argument : -Dcode=882.

I had the following error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: And near line 1, column 697 [SELECT distinct d FROM com.natixis.smartcontestation.emetteur.entite.ReglementClient r JOIN FETCH d.etablissement e And r.statut in('Validé') And e.code =  ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
```

Comment: actually it seems to work, but the HQL is wrong, your SQL for the queryString differs from the one in the stacktrace, specifically "JOIN FETCH d.etablissement e And r.statut in('Validé') And e.code =  " seems to be the problem, afaik you can not use AND directly after JOIN FETCH, it should be WHERE or WITH

Comment: My query is : SELECT distinct d FROM ReglementClient r JOIN FETCH d.etablissement e WHERE r.statut in('Validé') And e.code = #{jobParameters[code]}. I think the problem is due to the fact that it could not retrieve the #{jobParameters[code]}. I run the batch with the argument 'code' using -Dcode=882

Comment: That is invalid JPQL (it is not SQL!). Please look in a decent JPQL reference ... about "IN" keyword and WHERE clauses. There is no "#" symbol in JPQL!

Comment: So how can I retrieve dynamically e.code, as I explained thios value is available in my batch inputs

Comment: Nobody can tell you how since you don't post your ENTITY class so they don't know what e.code is, or r.statut. Maybe this "#{jobParameters[code]}" would be a simple ":myParam" ... but then maybe not since it isn't defined

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify normal parameter syntax in the jpql, use the parameterValues property on the reader to set the jobParameter

```
<bean id="Reader" scope="step"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory"
              ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <property name="queryString"
              value="SELECT distinct d FROM ReglementClient r 
               JOIN FETCH d.etablissement e 
               WHERE e.code = :code
               And r.statut in('Validé')
            " />

    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="code" value="#{jobParameters[code]}"/>
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34900569/62201, it should work with the jobParameter inside the SQL

Comment: Hmm ok, might be an issue with xml decoding then, not using CDATA

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortently I had this error : Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'

Comment: do you access the writer before/out of step scope?

Comment: or perhaps step scope isn't initialized correctly http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#step-scope

Comment: Well I fixed this problem by adding scope="step" to my writer. Now my issue is that my batch could not retrieve the jobParameters[code]. When I debbug I have this :

Comment: 2016-07-01 12:37:40,510 [QueryTranslatorImpl                     ] WARN  | firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
Hibernate: /* SELECT distinct d FROM ReglementClient r                                   
JOIN FETCH d.etablissement e                       
where And e.code = :code And r.statut in('Validé') from BY9_REGLEMENTCLIENT reglementc0_ inner join BY9_ETABLISSEMENT etablissem2_ on dossiereme1_.etablissement_id=etablissem2_.id where and etablissem2_.code=? and (reglementc0_.statut in ('Validé')).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116184/discussion-between-nabil-salah-and-andreas).

Answer (score 0):

if you use the standard spring batch mechanism to [run jobs from the commandline](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#runningJobsFromCommandLine), you need to follow the right pattern for the jobparameters

> These arguments must be passed in with the path first and the name
>   second. All arguments after these are considered to be JobParameters
>   and must be in the format of 'name=value':

```
bash$ java CommandLineJobRunner endOfDayJob.xml endOfDay schedule.date(date)=2007/05/05
```